# Magento 1.9.3.1 Quck Search Not working

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, search, catalogsearch

Magento Search Not Working.
Search Result: Your search returns no results.

What I have already done.

1. Visibility of the Product is set to Catalog, Search
2. Product Attribute name, SKU, color is set to Yes in Quick Search and is Global.
3. Tried with all Like,FullText,Combine in System->Catalog->Catalog Search.
4. Cleared Cache and Reindexing done several times.
5. Every Category including the root category is set to Yes is_anchor
6. And Did most of the solution given on StackOverflow.

Currently Using Theme Zorka.

Result After I search for a Product or Sku

[image]

SQL Query -->

SELECT `e`.*, `search_result`.`relevance`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalogsearch_result` AS `search_result` ON search_result.product_id=e.entity_id AND search_result.query_id='111'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='19' AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '2'

Comment: Your product is salable? stock ok?

Comment: Yes the product appears on the site. Just the Search is not Working. Inventory is more than 50. Product is in Stock.

Comment: Fine, nothing in var/log/*.log ?

Comment: Flat tables enabled ?

Comment: Done enabling the flat tables, reindexed , cleared cache, and got the same result. In log I debuged and got the query and fired using mysql but there were no result. Please Help

Comment: The product is in the good scope ? (website? store? store_view?)

Comment: Sorry I did not get the question .I have set Visibility to Catalog,Search ,  Website to Main Website , And Attributes name,sku ,color to global scope. ...

Comment: Can you add your sql query in question?

Comment: done @Nolwennig

Comment: Magento default search not good better you can install some 3rd party search extension.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many attributes have **Use in Quick Search** value **Yes**.

Please check and set value for **Use in Quick Search** to **Yes** only for Name, Sku and Description (if you want).

Set **No** for **Use in Quick Search** for all other attributes.

After doing so, do the reindexing and then check by searching again.

Comment: This seems already done